Pages are getting skipped in a step of a job in Spring Batch
Context: I am currently working on reading data from a database using pagination. To achieve this, I am using a RepositoryItemReader with a batch size of 1000. The reader fetches data from the database based on the created_at and status columns. Once the transactions have been read, I want to update them to a CANCELLED status. While the update process seems to be working, I have noticed that not all transactions are being updated.
After updating the transactions for a batch, I want to send those transactions to a Kafka topic that another service is listening to.
Issue: The job skips almost half of the pages because it updates the transaction status, which is a filter criterion for the RepositoryItemReader.
Expected Behaviour: How can I get all of the pages in reader consistently?
Code Snippets
Repository
@Repository
public interface TransactionPagingAndSortingRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Transaction, String> {
    Page<Transaction> findByCreatedAtBeforeAndStatusIn(ZonedDateTime currentDateTime, List<TransactionStatus> transactionStatuses, Pageable pageable);
}


Reader config
@Bean
public RepositoryItemReader<Transaction> reader() {
    Map<String, Sort.Direction> sortBy = new HashMap<>();
    sortBy.put("createdAt", Sort.Direction.ASC);

    ZonedDateTime currenZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")).minusDays(1);

    var transactionStatus = new ArrayList<>();

    transactionStatus.add(TransactionStatus.NEW);

    return new RepositoryItemReaderBuilder<Transaction>()
            .name("TransactionItemReader")
            .repository(transactionPagingAndSortingRepository)
            .methodName("findByCreatedAtBeforeAndStatusIn")
            .arguments(currenZonedDateTime, transactionStatus)
            .pageSize(1000)
            .sorts(sortBy)
            .saveState(true)
            .build();
}

Processor config
@Bean
public ItemProcessor<Transaction, Transaction> processor() {
    return item -> {
        item.setStatus(TransactionStatus.CANCELLED);
        item.setUpdatedAt(ZonedDateTime.now());
      return item;
    };
}

Writer config
@Bean
public ItemWriter<Transaction> writer() {
    return items -> {};
}

Step config
@Bean
Step cancelOldTransactionsStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager) {
    return new StepBuilder("cancelOldTransactionsStep", jobRepository)
            .<Transaction, Transaction> chunk(1000, platformTransactionManager)
            .reader(reader())
            .processor(processor())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}

Job config
@Bean
Job cancelOldTransactionsJob(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager) {
    return new JobBuilder("cancelOldTransactionsJob", jobRepository)
        .start(cancelOldTransactionsStep(jobRepository, platformTransactionManager))
        .build();
}

Updated Context

Why not just do this with a single query to update all in one go? That being said don't use paging for this if you are updating fields that are part of the select as well. Instead write a query and use the JpaCursorItemReader which will use a streaming result to obtain the results which will get y ou all the information. But as mentioned I would write a simply update query which updates everything in one go (if you can write the select query you can write the update as well).

Thanks, @M.Deinum for the response!
I require paging as I am unsure how many transactions are in the database. That's why I want to update the transactions in batches instead of in one go. Secondly, after reading the records, I also have to send them to a Kafka topic that another service is listening to. Sorry for the second piece of information. I have updated the context.

1 go would be one query, no read. Which would be a magnitude faster. Anyway as stated use the JpaCursorItemReader with a query instead of paging use a proper chunk size and you will achieve the same (and slightly faster probably as well).

Thank you @M.Deinum! JpaCursorItemReader worked nicely.
